# Cutting shell based mesh with python

Tags: python, mesh

I'm trying to practice mesh manipulation and trim off a piece of the mesh shown in the picture. The piece to be trimmed off is all elements to the right of the rib, as shown by the arrow. What's the most efficient way to this? Are there any python libraries that can make this easier?
[Shell based mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuzaA.png)

The method that I'm thinking of currently involves finding the intersection nodes between the two parts and then identifying the edges of the intersection. After that I'd chose a first triangle which lies on the intersection edge on the side which I want to cut then walk through each triangle that the first triangle touches and then repeat for each triangle the next triangles touch till I go through all triangles on the side while never going past the intersection boundary. I'm not sure whether there's an easier/more efficient way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

You have got plenty of python libraries to do this task, but I will recommend two:

- blender3D is a complete suit for 3D editing and render. It includes a python library, named bpy, that you can use to to program your own algorithms, with the advantage that the render is seen in real time. Very powerful, but also a bit complex. Start reading https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html
- pymeshlab is a library for programming geometric algorithms, as a way to automate anything you can do with meshlab. It include lots of simple and complex algorithms (named filters) as 'cut a mesh with a plane' or 'simplify a mesh to xxx triangles'. The advantage is that you can try an algorithm using meshlab, then program the algorithm using pymeshlab. Start reading at https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- more alternatives are CGAL, or libIGL.

Respect to your problem.  Your algorithm will work with simple meshes but you can go into trouble if the input mesh has a complex geometry. I would go using cuts using planes, or using boolean operators on the surfaces.